# how can I manage this?

Tags: math

I need help with this:

- What is an equation of the line that goes through (−1, −3) and is perpendicular to the
  line 2x+7y+5=0?
  need code in python

Comment: Note that this site is for programming questions, not for help with straightforward math homework. Anyway, you should always show the work you already tried.  Did you reread the corresponding chapter of your class math book? Did you read that a line perpendicular to `Ax+By + C = 0` is of the form `Bx - Ay + K = 0`? You might want to fill in your variables and calculate K?

Comment: Thank you, I just need python code for this equation

Comment: What does your question have to do with Python/code?

Comment: The python code, using [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), would be `Eq(B*x - A*y + K, 0)`.  Without sympy, equations usuallly aren't represented in code, though they will be used behind the scene to arrive at certain calculations.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service. If you have written code and you are having trouble with it, post it and maybe we can offer advice. If you want someone to write the code for you, see our [job site](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs)..

Answer (score 1):

The line  `2x + 7y + 5 = 0` has slope `-2/7`, so a line perpendicular to this must have slope equal to the negative reciprocal of this, which is `7/2`. So the desired line is of the form `y = (7/2)x + c`. Now since `(-1, -3)` lies on the line, we must have `-3 = (7/2)*(-1) + c`, which gives `c = 1/2`. Hence the equation of the desired line is `y = (7/2)x + 1/2`, which can also be written as `7x - 2y + 1 = 0`.